# Writing accelerometer data

Tags: android, accelerometer

I want my application to run in the background as well as write a value in the file. I have code for back button pressed, but it misses few values to write in a file. I have the below code in OnCreate() method of MainActivity.

```
    mHandler = new Handler();

        runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
//                sensorManager.registerListener(MainActivity.this, accel,
//                        SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
                mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
//                        sensorManager.unregisterListener(MainActivity.this);
                        firstValueInInterval=true;
                        mHandler.postDelayed(runnable,1000);
                    }
                },500);

            }
        };
```

and then, I write the values when onSensorChanged() is called every time.

```
 x = event.values[0];
 y = event.values[1];
 z = event.values[2];
 AccelData data = new AccelData(currentTime, x, y, z);
 sensorData.add(data);
 fs.writeToFile(sensorData);
 sensorData = new ArrayList<AccelData>();
```

and below is the code for back button presses, onResume and onPause().

```
public void onBackPressed() {

    moveTaskToBack(true);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mHandler.postDelayed(runnable,500);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mHandler.postDelayed(runnable,500);
    //sensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
}
```

I want this application to run 24*7 and write the data as well.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I get your code, Im not to familiar with the Android programming but I'll try to answer by suggesting a different approach.
Couldn't you perform those actions in a background thread which will be startet somewhere? That way you dont have to create a new runnable every time.

Also be aware that you produce a lot of data, depending on the sample rate. That will be very energy consuming and will produce a rather big file.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your concern, but I am looking to store the data because then I will be recognising what human activity the person was doing. So to know what a person is doing during the entire period, I need to store the data.